# How to stop a C# client application responding to a Basic Authentication 401 response

Tags: c#, basic-authentication

My C# application uses HttpWebClientProtocol to talk to my server. It has to use Windows authentication to authenticate with my server. The server only allows Windows authentication.

My problem is that when using HttpWebRequest this configuration is subject to a man-in-the-middle attack whereby when the server sends back

```
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
```

this can be intercepted and changed to

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="some.domain"
```

I've spent the day trawling the Internet and looking at the .net code, but I can't see a way of failing the request and not sending credentials back to the server with a basic auth header.

Comment: This is only vulnerable if you communicate with the server via base HTTP, rather than HTTPS. If you're talking to the server via HTTPS, as you should **always** do for authentication to an HTTP endpoint, the MitM attack will fail unless you've also been compromised to trust the attackers false certificate. And in that case you're _already compromised_, so the vulnerability is no longer interesting.

Comment: That is indeed the case. Unfortunately we have customers who use HTTP, so I was looking for a compromise.

Comment: If you're using HTTP for authentication and you have MitM concerns, you've already failed, because the password or authentication token is going through the network in clear text. They don't even need to alter anything: they can just steal the token and then pretend to be you from their own endpoint.

Comment: Plain text comms are not only vulnerable to MITM but also simple sniffing, easier attack because there is no need to put themselves in the middle and fake being the sender or the receiver of the traffic.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your comments, it's appreciated. Whilst HTTPS is obviously the way to go, our software still supports HTTP connections. I had hoped there there would be a way to stop a client supporting Basic Auth as it is simple to stop a server supporting it.